# What is the reason for this strange behaviour when passing struct by pointer to a goroutine?

Tags: go, pointers, goroutine

### TL;DR:

Passing a struct variable by reference to a go-routine apparently causes the wrong variable to be used sometimes (maybe if the variable is an element in an array? -- not sure if that matters or not). **What is is the reason for this?** In other words, how do pointers and go-routines interfere with each other?

### Working example

Consider the following code ([Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BlioV682aZ8)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Job struct {
    foo int
}

func main() {
    var jobs []Job
    jobs = []Job{}

    var jobsCount = 10

    for i := 0; i < jobsCount; i++ {
        jobs = append(jobs, Job{foo: i})
    }

    fmt.Println(jobs)

    for i, job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Starting '%d' '%+v'\n", i, job)
        go func(i int, job *Job) {
            fmt.Printf("Processing '%d' job '%+v'\n", i, job)
        }(i, &job)
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

Sample output:

```
[{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9}]
Starting '0' '{foo:0}'
Starting '1' '{foo:1}'
Starting '2' '{foo:2}'
Starting '3' '{foo:3}'
Starting '4' '{foo:4}'
Starting '5' '{foo:5}'
Starting '6' '{foo:6}'
Starting '7' '{foo:7}'
Starting '8' '{foo:8}'
Starting '9' '{foo:9}'
Processing '7' job '&{foo:9}'    <---
Processing '3' job '&{foo:7}'
Processing '2' job '&{foo:4}'
Processing '6' job '&{foo:8}'
Processing '0' job '&{foo:4}'
Processing '9' job '&{foo:9}'    <---
Processing '4' job '&{foo:6}'
Processing '8' job '&{foo:9}'    <---
Processing '5' job '&{foo:6}'
Processing '1' job '&{foo:4}'
```

We can notice the following:

- The struct `{foo: 9}` is processed by more than one go-routine, while some of them (e.g. `{foo: 1}` are not processed at all. *This is the unexpected part.*
- The loop spawning the go-routines correctly goes through the whole array. *(This is expected.)*
- The counter (`i`) is passed correctly to the go-routine. *(This is also expected.)*

### Further discussion

Let's pass the struct by value, instead of pointer ([whole code](https://go.dev/play/p/puR0jlbxETy) on playground):

```
    for i, job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Starting '%d' '%+v'\n", i, job)
        go func(i int, job Job) {
            fmt.Printf("Processing '%d' job '%+v'\n", i, job)
        }(i, job)
    }
```

The output in this case will be what we would have expected:

```
[{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9}]
Starting '0' '{foo:0}'
Starting '1' '{foo:1}'
Starting '2' '{foo:2}'
Processing '0' job '{foo:0}'
Starting '3' '{foo:3}'
Starting '4' '{foo:4}'
Starting '5' '{foo:5}'
Starting '6' '{foo:6}'
Starting '7' '{foo:7}'
Starting '8' '{foo:8}'
Starting '9' '{foo:9}'
Processing '3' job '{foo:3}'
Processing '6' job '{foo:6}'
Processing '4' job '{foo:4}'
Processing '5' job '{foo:5}'
Processing '7' job '{foo:7}'
Processing '2' job '{foo:2}'
Processing '8' job '{foo:8}'
Processing '9' job '{foo:9}'
Processing '1' job '{foo:1}'
```

Same if the function is invoked on the same go-routine as the loop ([whole code](https://go.dev/play/p/E55Fork9vIo)):

```
    for i, job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Starting '%d' '%+v'\n", i, job)
        func(i int, job *Job) {
            fmt.Printf("Processing '%d' job '%+v'\n", i, job)
        }(i, &job)
    }
```

```
[{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9}]
Starting '0' '{foo:0}'
Processing '0' job '&{foo:0}'
Starting '1' '{foo:1}'
Processing '1' job '&{foo:1}'
Starting '2' '{foo:2}'
Processing '2' job '&{foo:2}'
Starting '3' '{foo:3}'
Processing '3' job '&{foo:3}'
Starting '4' '{foo:4}'
Processing '4' job '&{foo:4}'
Starting '5' '{foo:5}'
Processing '5' job '&{foo:5}'
Starting '6' '{foo:6}'
Processing '6' job '&{foo:6}'
Starting '7' '{foo:7}'
Processing '7' job '&{foo:7}'
Starting '8' '{foo:8}'
Processing '8' job '&{foo:8}'
Starting '9' '{foo:9}'
Processing '9' job '&{foo:9}'
```

Comment: The first program passes the address of the single variable `job` to all goroutines. The variable is overwritten on each iteration of the loop. The program has a data race.  Pass a unique pointer to each goroutine. Here's one way to do it: `for i  := range jobs { go func(i int, j *job) { ... }(i, &jobs[i])`

Comment: Thanks, so the variable `job` is somehow the same for all the iterations?

Comment: Also, if that's the case, then `i` is also the same variable, so why is there no race in that case?

Comment: The program declares a single variable `job` and that variable is assigned on each iteration of the loop. There is not race on `i` because the *value* in the variable `i` is passed to goroutine.  When the loop modifies the variable `i`, there is no change to the *values* passed to the previously started goroutines.

Comment: [Fixing For Loops in Go 1.22](https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview)

Comment: Thanks guys, now I get it. The question is now closed, so I cannot write an answer, just summarize the issue in this comment. 1.) The problem has nothing to do with go-routines. 2.) It basically boils down to the fact that range variable is loop-scoped, i.e. in each iteration the next value is _copied_ into the _same_ variable.